# Remote autocomplete is not working Angucomplete Alt

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying angularjs  autocomplete [Angucomplete Alt](https://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/#example5) here I copied same code and running on mylocal host but this is not showing any result

I am searching term ssss it is showing error

`GET https://api.github.com/search/repositoriessafa 404 (Not Found)`

My code is

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["angucomplete-alt"]);
myApp.controller('TestController', function ($scope, $http) {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angucomplete-alt/3.0.0/angucomplete-alt.min.js"></script>

 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController">
 
  <div angucomplete-alt
     id="ex5"
     placeholder="Search projects"
     pause="500"
     selected-object="selectedProject"
     remote-url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories"
     remote-url-request-formatter="remoteUrlRequestFn"
     remote-url-data-field="items"
     title-field="name"
     description-field="description"
     minlength="2"
     input-class="form-control form-control-small"
     match-class="highlight">
   </div>
   </body>
```

Is there any thing missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you open your dev tools you can see the remote call is not made in right way.

you must add query string

try to edit your remote-url in this

```
remote-url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q="
```

and it will work